# Porting Decryption Function From PHP to NodeJs

Tags: php, node.js, cryptojs

I have some problem when porting a function from PHP to NodeJS. I have tried implement this PHP code with Node JS, but its not working.

This is the code in PHP

```
   <?php 
        require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';
    
        // function decrypt
        function stringDecrypt($key, $string){
            
      
            $encrypt_method = 'AES-256-CBC';
    
            // hash
            $key_hash = hex2bin(hash('sha256', $key));
      
            // iv - encrypt method AES-256-CBC expects 16 bytes - else you will get a warning
            $iv = substr(hex2bin(hash('sha256', $key)), 0, 16);
    
            $output = openssl_decrypt(base64_decode($string), $encrypt_method, $key_hash, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv);
      
            return $output;
        }
        
    ?>
```

This is my code in NodeJs

```
    function decryptResponse(timestamp, string, key) {
        var key_hash = hex2bin(crypto.createHash("sha256").update(key).digest('hex'));
        var iv = key_hash.substr(0,16);
        var decoder = crypto.createDecipheriv('aes-256-cbc', key_hash, iv);
        var output = decoder.update(Buffer.from(string).toString('base64'),'base64','utf8') += decoder.final('utf8');
        console.log("Decrypt Result : ", output); //Not Showing on Log
    }

function hex2bin(hex) {
    var bytes = [];
    var str;
    for(var i=0; i< hex.length-1; i+=2){
        bytes.push(parseInt(hex.substr(i, 2), 16));
    }
    str = String.fromCharCode.apply(String, bytes);

    return str;
  }
```

This function is called when I get the response from API and need to send it to the user.

```
var decompressedResponse = decryptResponse(timestamp, response.data.response, key);  
res.send(decompressedResponse);
```

I need this function to decrypt a response from API so I really need this one working. Thank you for your help.

Comment: In the PHP code the `decompress()` function is not used, why do you post it (and why is it applied at all in the NodeJS code)? `hex2bin()` in the NodeJS code is also not defined.

Comment: @Topaco sorry, I will add the hex2bin() on nodejs, for the PHP, I dont know much about it because its not mine. The basic is, you need to decrypt the API response with aes-256-cbc, then decompressed the decrypt result with LZString

Comment: I would recommend to ask the decompress issue in a separate question (if needed at all). Currently, your information on this is inconsistent, which makes it difficult to answer the whole question:  In the PHP code `decompress()` is not called at all and in the NodeJS code the implementation is missing.

Comment: @Topaco Ah okay, I will delete that, because the main problem is the decryption. Thank you for your advice

Comment: @Topaco Thank you for your advice. Remove the hex2bin function and return key hash as a bffer and now its working. Can you please using that as an answer? I will accept it as a correct answer. Thank you.

Comment: Sure, I' ve summarized my comments as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `hex2bin()` function is not needed and can be removed.

Also, it's easier to determine key and IV as buffer.

The ciphertext is currently Base64 encoded a second time in `update()`. To avoid this, it should be passed *directly* to `update()`.

And the concatenation of the results of `update()` and `final()` call must be done with `+` instead of `+=` (which is probably just a typo or copy/paste error).

Overall:

```php
function decryptResponse(timestamp, string, key) {
    var key_hash = crypto.createHash("sha256").update(key).digest(); // remove hex2bin; use Buffer
    var iv = key_hash.slice(0,16); // use Buffer
    var decoder = crypto.createDecipheriv('aes-256-cbc', key_hash, iv);
    var output = decoder.update(string,'base64','utf8') + decoder.final('utf8'); // don't Base64 encode twice, pass ciphertext directly; apply + instead of +=
    console.log("Decrypt Result : ", output); 
}
```

---

Note that it's insecure to use the key or a part of the key as IV. Usually the (non-secret) IV is randomly generated for each encryption and passed along with the ciphertext (typically concatenated).

Also, using a hash as key derivation function is insecure. Instead, a reliable key derivation function such as PBKDF2 should be applied.